# distance from point to plane in a particular direction

Tags: math, geometry, linear-algebra

Given:

1. a point `(x1, y1, z1)`
2. a direction vector `(a1, b1, c1)`
3. a plane `ax + by + cz + d = 0`

How can I find the distance `D` from the point to the plane along that vector?

Thanks

Comment: It's not really a programming question, you are looking for a mathematical formula. Questions that ask to find or recommend a software library are off-topic.

Comment: Changed tags and removed software recommendations question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about [math.se] instead of programming or software development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a library. You need math.
The vector will hit the plane in this location

```
(x,y,z) = (x1+l*a1, y1+l*b1, z1+l*c1)
```

with an L so that

```
a * (x1 + a1*L) + b * (y1 + b1*L) + c * (z1 + c1*L) + d = 0
```

A few equivalent changes

```
L * ( a1*a + b1*b + c1*c) +  (a*x1 + b*y1 + c*z1 + d) = 0
L * ( a1*a + b1*b + c1*c) = -(a*x1 + b*y1 + c*z1 + d)
L                         = -(a*x1 + b*y1 + c*z1 + d) / ( a1*a + b1*b + c1*c)
```

You can calculate L that way (assuming no division by 0).
Then from L you can calculate D, the distance between the point and the crossing of plane and direction.
As you yourself put it (faster and better than I was phrasing in my head), the direction vector needs to be unit normalized beforehand to make actually L=D.

Comment: The s->c edit was good, thanks for noticing. Sorry that it got trampled.

Comment: Thanks this helps. I suppose the directional vector needs to be unit normalized else this formula doesn't work.

Comment: Well spotted. Me too just a few seconds before.